# What happens when Scheduler function execution does not get completed and the scheduler recalls the function

Tags: python, database, scheduler

I am calling a function via a a scheduler after every 5 seconds.In this function,i am performing some database operations.So my question is,if the function execution is not completed and the scheduler re calls the same function,then what would happen to the function that was currently getting executed.

Below is a screenshot of the code with the scheduler.

[image: Screenshot of code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just try it. There will be something output and tell you that the task is still running, so it won't run again this time, it will be checked next time.

For example:

```
Execution of job "a (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2018-04-25 14:09:57 CST)" skipped: maximum number of running instances reached (1)
```

Comment: The function execution takes like some milliseconds.So i really can't check that output and the data i have right now is not sufficient.

Comment: Did I misunderstand your question? I think you want to know will an uncompleted function be executed again by scheduler. The example I give is the output generated by `scheduler` itself. Let me simplify my expression, it won't unless you set `max_instances > 1`.

Comment: So will it complete the earlier function first before recalling it again.Even though it make take more than the duration i have specified in the trigger parameter.And the no of instance is 1.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It will skip all execution until the earlier function completes. You just needn't to worry about it.